# How to take AWR report from dynatrace?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, dynatrace

I am new to performance analysis of DB.

1. How to pull AWR report from dynatrace?
2. What parameters we are monitoring in AWR report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You pull it from ORACLE.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Dynatrace** enables monitoring of your entire infrastructure including your hosts, processes, and network. You can schedule AWR report on email trigger.

**2. What parameters we are monitoring in AWR report?**
You have check combination of AWR report. using single AWR report willl not give clear idea.

dependen on issue you have to see different section.

The main sections in an AWR report include:

Report Summary:  overall summary of the instance during the snapshot period, and it contains important aggregate summary information.

Cache Sizes (end): size of each SGA region after AMM has changed them. This information can be compared to the original init.ora parameters at the end of the AWR report.

Load Profile:  shows important rates expressed in units of per second and transactions per second.

Instance Efficiency Percentages: With a target of 100%, these are high-level ratios for activity in the SGA.

Shared Pool Statistics: T good summary of changes to the shared pool during the snapshot period.

Top 5 Timed Events:  It shows the top wait events and can quickly show the overall database bottleneck.

Wait Events Statistics Section: shows a breakdown of the main wait events in the database including foreground and background database wait events as well as time model, operating system, service, and wait classes statistics.

Wait Events: This AWR report section provides more detailed wait event information for foreground user processes which includes Top 5 wait events and many other wait events that occurred during the snapshot interval.

Background Wait Events: This section is relevant to the background process wait events.

Time Model Statistics: Time mode statistics report how database-processing time is spent. This section contains detailed timing information on particular components participating in database processing.

Operating System Statistics: The stress on the Oracle server is important, and this section shows the main external resources including I/O, CPU, memory, and network usage.

Service Statistics: The service statistics section gives information about how particular services configured in the database are operating.